# How does the winged-edge structure for meshes work?

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, implementation, mesh

I'm implementing an algorithm in which I need manipulate a mesh, adding and deleting edges quickly and iterating quickly over the edges adjacent to a vertex in CCW or CW order.

The winged-edge structure is used in the description of the algorithm I'm working from, but I can't find any concise descriptions of how to perform those operations on this data structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've learned about it in University but that was a while ago.

In response to this question i've searched the web too for any good documentation, found none that is good, but we can go through a quick example for CCW and CW order and insertion/deletion here.
Have a look at this table and graphic:
[image]
 from this page:

http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/model/winged-e.html

The table gives only the entry for one edge `a`, in a real table you have this row for every edge. You can see you get the:

- left predecessor,
- left successor,
- right predecessor,
- right successor

but here comes the critical point: it gives them relative to the *direction* of the edge which is `X->Y` in this case, and when it is right-traversed `(e->a->c)`.

So for the CW-order of going through the graph this is very easy to read: edge `a` left has right-successor `c` and then you look into the row for edge `c`.

Ok, this table is easy to read for CW-order traversal; for CCW you have to think "from which edge did i come from when i walked this edge backwards". Effectively you get the next edge in CCW-order by taking the left-traverse-predecessor in this case `b` and continue with the row-entry for edge `b` in the same manner.

Now insertion and deletion: It is clear that you cant just remove the edge and think that the graph would still consist of only triangles; during deletion you have to **join** two vertices, for example `X` and `Y` in the graphic. To do this you first have to make sure that everywhere the edge `a` is referred-to we have to fix that reference.

So where can `a` be referred-to? only in the edges `b,c,d and e` (all other edges are too far away to know `a`) plus in the vertex->edge-table if you have that (but let's only consider the edges-table in this example).

As an example of how we have to fix edges lets take a look at `c`. Like `a`, `c` has a left and right pre- and successor (so 4 edges), which one of those is `a`? We cannot know that without checking because the table-entry for `c` can have the node `Y` in either its Start- or End-Node. So we have to check which one it is, let's assume we find that `c` has Y in its Start-Node, we then have to check whether `a` is `c's` right predecessor (which it is and which we find out by looking at `c's` entry and comparing it to `a`) OR whether it is `c's` right *successor*. "Successor??" you might ask? Yes because remember the two "left-traverse"-columns are relative to going the edge backward. So, now we have found that `a` is `c's` right predecessor and we can fix that reference by inserting `a's` right predecessor. Continue with the other 3 edges and you are done with the edges-table. Fixing an additional `Node->Vertices` is trivial of course, just look into the entries for X and Y and delete `a` there.

Adding edges is *basically* the reverse of this fix-up of 4 other edges BUT with a little twist. Lets call the node which we want to split `Z` (it will be split into `X` and `Y`). You have to take care that you split it in the right direction because you can have either `d` and `e` combined in a node or `e` and `c` (like if the new edge is horizontal instead of the vertical `a` in the graphic)! You first have to find out between which 2 edges of the soon-to-be `X` and between which 2 edges of `Y` the new edge is added: You just choose which edges shall be on one node and which on the other node: In this example graphic:  choose that you want `b`, `c` and the 2 edges to the north in between them on one node, and it follows that the other edges are on the other node which will become `X`. You then find by vector-subtraction that the new edge `a` has to be between b and c, not between say c and one of the 2 edges in the north. The vector-subtraction is the desired position of the new `X` minus the desired position of `Y`.

Comment: I'll be looking forward to that. Accept coming if there's a readable description of those operations :)

Comment: here it is. finished writing :) of course, for addition of edges you have to do the reverse.

Comment: well, maybe adding edges is not quite as easy as reversing it, i will add a bit about that to the answer, 1 minute.